# SBT how to create custom command

Tags: scala, sbt

Given I have `build.sbt`

```
name := """app"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

// <-- some other code -->

import Fixtures._

lazy val fixtures = inputKey[Unit]("Generating Cassandra fixtures")

fixtures := {
  Fixtures.generate()
}
```

and Fixtures.scala in `project` directory

```
object Fixtures {
  def generate (): Unit = {
    println("generating fixtures")
  }
}
```

I am able to run command `./activator fixtures` and I am getting **"generating fixtures"**

But how can I call some service, let say `GenerateUserFixtureService.scala` but from `app/scala/com/MyProject/Service` directory. Import package does not work, because `project` directory belongs to different package. I am not able to import anything to `Fixtures.scala` from Play

```
|
|___app
|   |__scala
|      |__com
|         |__MyProject
|            |__Service
|               |--GenerateUserFixtureService.scala
|___project
|   |--Fixtures.scala
|___
    |--build.sbt
```

Actually the question is, why I am able to import to `build.sbt` only files from `project` directory. Or how can I call another files from `app` dir?

Or maybe the way I am thinking is completely wrong. I just want to create some command `upload:fixtures` `send:emails` etc, and call some scala class. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For creating a custom command you must specify a function which corresponds to the logic of your command. Let's consider a few examples:
first just print hello message:

```
 def helloSbt = Command.command("hello") { state =>
        println("Hello, SBT")
        state
    }

commands += helloSbt
```

just put this code into `build.sbt`, `commands` is `project key` which is present into `sbt.Keys` as `val commands = SettingKey[Seq[Command]]`

Of course, you can manage the statement of your command like success or fail:

```
def failJustForFun = Command.single("fail-condidtion") {
        case (state, "true") => state.fail
        case (state, _) => state
    }
```

You can change the color in console for specific part of your command or output of this command via leveraging of `DefaultParsers`:

```
    lazy val color = token( Space ~> ("blue" ^^^ "4" | "green" ^^^ "2") )
    lazy val select = token( "fg" ^^^ "3" | "bg" ^^^ "4" )
    lazy val setColor = (select ~ color) map { case (g, c) => "\033[" + g + c + "m" }
```

And like alternative, you can extend `xsbti.AppMain` and implement -  [your own logic](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Command-Line-Applications.html)